# Why does chewing gum sometimes change its texture

Tags: texture, chemistry

Although this is more a general food related question, I wonder why chewing gum sometimes changes its texture and looses its chewy quality?

Comment: I've actually never experienced this and I wonder if you mean that the texture changes while you are chewing it or some time (weeks or months) after buying it.

Comment: It does not happen often but I may be chewing it for some times, even some hours and then suddenly the texture changes and the gum kind of crumbles and becomes floury.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with the type of hydrocolloid that is being used in the specific gum you are chewing. Most are pretty stable but also need a specific combination of pH, moisture, and temperature to stay within their desired texture range. A comprehensive understanding of the different types of hydrocolloids can be found here:

http://blog.khymos.org/recipe-collection/